# IBM Worklight 6.1: How to implement HTTPS secure connection between mobile app with Worklight Server?

Tags: https, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, worklight-server, worklight-security

I have an requirement to implement HTTPS secure connection between Mobile application with IBM Worklight server.

Setup I have is,

Mobile App -> IHS -> IBM Worklight server.

Is there a standard way to implement secure connection between Mobile app with Worklight server?

Note:
IBM Worklight server is running on Liberty profile.

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation topic: [Typical topologies of an IBM Worklight instance](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_typical_topology_of_an_ibm_wor.html)

IMO in front of the Worklight Server you should have a "gateway" server, a load balancer or  Apache, that receives HTTPS connections; you set up and point your application to it. This server then routes the requests to the Worklight Server.

Any IT department is likely to understand how to configure an appropriate secure setup...